# How To Handle Null In C#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Here I am trying to get FormName if exists form column FormName of table MainMenu, but before that I am trying to check whether column FormName consists form name or not by

```
var chkURL = uow.Repository<MainMenu>().GetAll().Where(x => x.MenuId
== getMenuId && x.IsVisible == 1).Select(x => x.FormName).FirstOrDefault().Any();
```

but it show an error **'Value cannot be null'** even though all parameters (i.e getMenuId , IsVisible = 1 ) consists correct data.
Below is my code

```
    public string GetChildNodeForm(string menuTitle)
    {
        var getMenuId = uow.Repository<MainMenu>().FindBy(x => x.MenuTitle == menuTitle && x.IsVisible == 1).FirstOrDefault().MenuId;
        var chkURL = uow.Repository<MainMenu>().GetAll().Where(x => x.MenuId == getMenuId && x.IsVisible == 1).Select(x => x.FormName).FirstOrDefault().Any();
        if (chkURL == true)
        {
            return uow.Repository<MainMenu>().FindBy(x => x.MenuId == getMenuId && x.IsVisible == 1).FirstOrDefault().FormName.Trim();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `if (chkURL == true)` ?? Why not `if(chkURL)`

Comment: Also, are you really fetching the same DB row three times?

Comment: Replace the `Where` in that line with `Any`, and remove everything after and including the `.Select()`. You just want to check if any exist, which is what `Any` does. With your current code, `FirstOrDefault` returns the first `FormName` that matches your condition, or `null` if none match, and then you try to call `Any` on that result.

Comment: Lets suppose FormName is not null but `FormName.Trim()` returns the empty string... do you want to return null or the empty string in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you're encountering in that line is that `FirstOrDefault` returns the first `FormName` that matches your condition, or `null` if none match, and then you try to call `Any` on that result.

If you were to replace the `Where` in that line with `Any`, and remove everything after it, then you would be checking if there were any items that meet the condition:

```
var chkURL = uow.Repository<MainMenu>().GetAll()
    .Any(x => x.MenuId == getMenuId && x.IsVisible == 1);
```

However, looking at your code, it appears that you're first looking up the menu id from the menu title, then you're checking again using the menu id to see if there are any items (?), and finally you're trying to get the form name by menu id.

Instead of querying for the same object three times, you can just do it once by simplifying your code to get the `FirstOrDefault` that matches the menu name, and if that's not null get the `FormName`, and if that's not null, `Trim` it and return the trimmed form name (or return `null` if anything was `null` along the way):

```
public string GetChildNodeForm(string menuTitle)
{
    return uow.Repository<MainMenu>().GetAll()
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.MenuTitle == menuTitle && x.IsVisible == 1)
        ?.FormName?.Trim();
}
```

Comment: Thank you that's worked and optimized my code. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Method `FirstOrDefault` might returns `null` so don't use `Any()` method here.

```
var formName = uow.Repository<MainMenu>()
               .GetAll()
               .Where(x => x.MenuId == getMenuId && x.IsVisible == 1)
               .Select(x => x.FormName)
               .FirstOrDefault();
if(formName != null ) 
 {
   //TODO
 }
```

Comment: Actually, `.FirstOrDefault().Any()` does **not** do the same as `.FirstOrDefault()`, so it must be verified that the bug was actually that `.Any()` was introduced, not that it couldn't handle null values. Perhaps `.Any()` should then be returned inside that if-statement instead, after verifying that `.FirstOrDefault()` returned an instance.

Comment: Might just be a simple case of writing `.FirstOrDefault()?.Any() ?? false`.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I thought `Any()` is an extension method on IEnumerables/IQueryables, and `FirstOrDefault()` delivers neither of those. So I'd be surprised if it even compiled.

Comment: @PeterB - I'm guessing that `x.FormName` is a `string`, which actually **is** an `IEnumerable<char>`. So `.Any()` is actually another way for testing if the string is not empty. Not sure about efficiency though.

Comment: A right, forgot about that. Well if I see it being used like that then I will strike it  as wrong/incorrect/confusing because there are much clearer ways to check if a string is empty.

Answer (score 1):

`!String.IsNullOrEmpty([linqQueryUntilFirstOrDefault()])` will check if there's a non-empty string matching the conditions without throwing an error if there is no result, and at least it is **designed for this exact purpose**, which is not the case of `.Any()` (as it throws `null` exception when your result is `null`)

Moreover, I'd advise you to replace the `var` tag with a `bool` so people reading the code don't get confused on what you expect the result to be, and then you can remove the `== true` on your `if` as `chkUrl` is already a boolean.

More generally, be careful with `.FirstOrDefault().[anything]` as `.FirstOrDefault()` can return `null`. So either use `.FirstOrDefault()?.[anything]` or try to write on several lines (there's nothing wrong in doing this, and you may gain in readability)